# Android Google Map move camera doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps

I've looked at everything I can find on this, and haven't found a solution.  I'm trying to do something very simple:

```
protected void moveCamera(final LatLng position, final float zoom) {
    getMap(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

            logger.debug("Moving map to " + position);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(position)
                    .zoom(zoom)
                    .build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }
    });
}
```

Nothing happens.  No errors, no camera movement. I've also tried `moveCamera` instead.  I've tried different types of calls to `CameraUpdateFactory`, I've tried moving and zooming separately, I've tried posting with a `Handler` with a delay.  Sometimes this works perfectly, but if I leave the fragment with the map and come back, then it doesn't work.  The map resets to latitude 0,0 and standard map type (it was set to hybrid) and I can't get it to do anything.  I know the method is getting called by logging statements.  Is there some kind of lifecycle thing I need to do to make sure the map can be restored?

I'd really prefer not to switch to Mapbox or something because that would be a lot of work to fix a little bug, but I need this to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for this camera issue.
You can change zoom level, radius.

```
int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    height = Math.round(0.45f*height);
    int padding = (int) (width * 0.10);

LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.include(new LatLng(INSERT_LAT,
                            INSERT_LNG)).build();
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = 
CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,width,height,padding);
    googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 1000, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following and it works fine:

```
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
height = Math.round(0.45f*height);
int padding = (int) (width * 0.10);


CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,width,height,padding);

// Add this where you want to move map camera
mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng("<pass_LatLng_here"));
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14)); //set the zoom level here
```

Comment: Why do you create a `CameraUpdate` and then not use it?

Comment: If I just use the `moveCamera` and `animateCamera` parts it does nothing. `LatLngBounds bounds = LatLngBounds.builder().build()` (which I assume is what you were going for since `builder` was not defined in your code snippet) produces this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the move camera inside the onPlaceSelected callback in Places Autocomplete api doesn't work.

I moved the moveCamera into a runOnUiThread and it's now working fine.

Comment: The reason is you were trying to do it from a background thread, and all map operations have to be on the main/UI thread.